# How to config port in docker

Tags: docker

What is the difference between starting Docker these ways?

1. `docker --net = host`
2. `docker -p 8200:8200 -p 34016:34016`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one shares the net namespace between the docker container and the host.

For example, a nethogs container launched without `--net=host` will not display much, see

see https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs_git/

if I do not put `--net=host` the docker container does not see any network card, so I get

`No devices to monitor. Use '-a' to allow monitoring loopback interfaces or devices that are not up/running`

It wil be the same with a OpenVPN container

you will notice that the pid and net namespaces of the host will be available to the container, in the command

`docker run -it --rm --net=host --pid=host k3ck3c/nethogs_git wlan0`

The second says that the port 8200 of the container will be published on the port 8200 of the host, and the same for the port 34016. To be more specific,

`-p 9000:10000`

means the port 10000 of the container will be published on the port 9000 of the host.